# Change country availability between app updates on Apple App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, updates, app-update

My app has an existing production release on Apple App Store.

Currently, all countries can download my app.

And I just made an update version of my app.

This time, I will publish my app worldwide except China.

Suppose user A in China had installed my app of old version.

And I'm going to publish a new version except China.

If this is the case, will user A get a new update?

I know that my app will be removed from Chinese App Store but I'm not sure people who already installed my app would get an update or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that user A **will not** get any more updates in accordance with your app.